# PInvoke on SafeArray of AnsiBStr

Tags: c#, unicode, pinvoke, dllimport, ansi

I have an old C++ DLL exporting functions with ASCII string output arguments.
I managed to use the first one like this :

```
[DllImport("MyLibrary.dll")]
private static extern int GetVersion(
    [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)]
    out string version);
```

The `AnsiBStr` type does the magic to convert ASCII to UTF-16 (unicode) and all is fine.

I have another function which uses a SafeArray of AnsiBStr. But I don't know how to do the same trick.
My code is the following and the result is an array of japanese glyphs because of the lack of ascii/unicode conversion.

```
[DllImport("MyLibrary.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern int GetList(
    [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, 
                    SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_BSTR)] 
    out string[] result);
```

There is nothing like `VarEnum.VT_ANSI_BSTR`, unfortunately...
What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2):

You can always write your marshalling method yourself and change the encoding. Try this:

```
[DllImport("MyLibrary.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern int GetList(
    [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, 
                    SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_BSTR)] 
    out string[] result);

private static string[] GetList()
{
    string[] arr;
    GetList(out arr);
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(arr[i]);
        arr[i] = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

You can also create a custom marshaller if you use lots of similar methods.

Comment: When I try VarEnum.VT_PTR as you suggest, I get this exception : "Specified array was not of the expected type".

Comment: @Tolokoban What if you simply omit `SafeArraySubType`?

Comment: If I omit `SafeArraySubType`, the runtime complains :
__Specified array was not of the expected type__

Comment: @Tolokoban With `out IntPtr[]` or `out string[]`? Try also just `out Array`, if neither of these worked.

Comment: `out string[]` is the only way to avoid the error message, but it is what I have tried in the first time and it has the problem to not convert ANSI to Unicode.

Comment: @Tolokoban If any possibility other than `out string` and `VT_BSTR` fails, you'll probably have to change the encoding of the string, or use C++/CLI. I've updated the code.